# javafx bidirectional change notification won't work?

Tags: java, javafx, bind

consider the following situation:

I am binding the string-property of a `TextField` to a float-property:

```
TextField txtField;
SimpleFloatProperty floatprop;

void bind(){
  txtField.textProperty().bindBidiretional(floatprop, NumberFormat.getInstance);
}
```

Furthermore, I want to check whether the value is positive and I want to reset the value if necessary:

```
floatprop.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {                
    SimpleFloatProperty prop = (SimpleFloatProperty)ov;
    if(t.floatValue() <= 0)
        prop.set(t1.floatValue());
    else
        prop.set(t.floatValue());
    }
});
```

That does not work. No matter what I type into my textfield, the value is not checked, i.e negative values are not reset.

Edit: With a litte bit of distance, I also see why. On setting `prop`, the changed-event will be triggered for a handy endless recursion. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide a SSCCE?

Comment: Well, I discovered, why it doesn't work. I now wonder how to make it work :D . See my edit for details.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked to do this check at the beginning of `changed`:

```
if (t != null && t.equals(t1))
    return;
```

Strangely, this way sometimes fails as well. Then, there is no other way than using a flag, like this:

```
MyListener implements ChangeListener<...>{
   boolean fired;
   public void changed(...){
      if(fired)
          return;
      fired = true;
      // Change the variable...
      fired = false; 
   }
}
```

I don't like the latter way, but it looks like there is no alternative.